# IPv6 address as hostname

Tags: web-server, ipv6

With IPv4 I don't have to buy a domain name to make my website available to everyone. I can just give people my IP address, they type it into their browser and there it is.

Is that supposed to work at all with IPv6? When I try going to my IPv6 address all browsers just make a google search with no results.

Comment: You don't have to buy a domain for every server.  You can buy one domain and use it for millions of servers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah that is supported. Just use `http://[IPv6-Address]`. The `[]` must be included.